# Sum of specific values of specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset which contains:

```
Column_A   Column_B   Column_C
1          55         23
1          65         14  
2          32         54
2          25         13  
3          69         28
3          14         56
```

Desired output:

Sum of **'Column_B'**+ **'Column_C'** taking into account same values of **Column_A**

total_of_11 = 55+65+23+14

total_of_22 = 32+25+54+13

Answer (score 2):

You can sum and then group:

```
res = df.eval('Total=Column_B + Column_C', inplace=False)\
        .groupby('Column_A')['Total'].sum().reset_index()

print(res)

   Column_A  Total
0         1    157
1         2    124
2         3    167
```

Comment: question, is res a shallow copy of df or a completely different object?

Comment: @Yuca, A new object.`df` is unchanged. Changing `res` will not impact `df`.

Comment: maybe `df.eval('Column_sum=Column_B + Column_C').groupby('Column_A')['Column_sum'].sum()
`

Comment: @Wen, Hmm, that doesn't work for me though on 0.19 (sry, old version). OK, I figured it out, it needs `inplace=False`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` on you Column_A

```
df.groupby('Column_A').sum().sum(axis=1)
```

Output

```
Column_A
1    157
2    124
3    167
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_index` and `sum`

```
df.set_index('Column_A').sum(level=0).sum(1)
Out[989]: 
Column_A
1    157
2    124
3    167
dtype: int64
```